# Enter Network Password

Tags: networking, network-shares, ip

When I try to open shared folder in another computer, it opens correctly. 
Ex : `\\192.168.1.1\folder1`

But When I try to enter `\\192.168.1.1\c`$ , it asks a Username and a Network password.
But that remote computer's account does not have a password. I made a password and try to access. But it doesn't let me accessing the C Drive.

Network Sharing is ON
Password sharing is OFF
Limit local account use of Blank Password is Disabled.

Remember , I can access shared folders, except c$ :/

Please help ... !

Answer (score 1):

Drive letter $ are automatic administrative shares by default only accessible to admin users. Try setting a password for the Administrator user, make sure the account is enabled and try again.

Comment: Now I tried. The username is Administrator. Password is 123456 which I use to log in. But didn't work :(

Comment: Are you sure the admin shares are active? http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/Windows2000/AdminTips/Security/RemoveAdminShares.html

Comment: Yes. They are active. C$ D$ E$ and F$

Comment: is it just c$ or all of the admin shares? have you checked the actual share permissions?

Comment: According to your link, I checked Shares on Computer management. It shows those 4 $ shares and description is "default share". I also use the Net Share command and it also showed that same detail. But how can I see the share permissions?

Comment: right click on the shared resource. note to check the comment to your original post (if you're running Win7+)